# Showing a table for open and closed tickets

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

This shows a table for open and closed tickets. The code for open tickets is identical with the closed tickets. I was trying to figure out a way to just write one code segment that will show both tables and use half of the code lines. With some changes I ended up to this code. With this code, if I iterate it twice and at at first use the word "open" and then rename it to "closed" then I will accomplish what I am after.

I looked around and figured out that I need to use a dynamic variable name. Something like `sum#{status}tickets` (pretty sure that something like that doesn't work) where the "status" variable will be at the first iteration "open" and then "closed" at the second one.

I was wondering if this is somehow possible (to iterate twice) and then dynamically set the variable's name.

```
   <% if sumopentickets == 0 %>
    <h3>Open Tickets</h3>
    <h4>No open tickets.</h3>
  <% else %>
   <h3>Open Tickets</h3>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket Number</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Submitted by</th>
      <th>Created at</th>
      <th colspan="2">Status</th>
    </tr>

    <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
    <% if ticket.status == "open" %>
    <% user = User.find(ticket.user_id) %>
     <tr>
        <td><%= ticket.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to ticket.title, ticket_path(ticket.url_token) %></td>
        <td><%= user.username %></td>
        <td><%= ticket.created_at.strftime("%H:%M, %B %d, %Y") %></td>
        <% if ticket.ticketmessages.last && ticket.ticketmessages.last.user_id %>
        <td>(user waiting for reply...)</td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <% end %>


  <% if sumclosedtickets == 0 %>
    <h3>Closed Tickets</h3>
    <h4>No closed tickets.</h3>
  <% else %>
  <h3>Closed Tickets</h3>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket Number</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Submitted by</th>
      <th>Created at</th>
      <th colspan="2">Status</th>
    </tr>

    <% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>
    <% if ticket.status == "closed" %>
      <% user = User.find(ticket.user_id) %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= ticket.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to ticket.title, ticket_path(ticket.url_token) %></td>
        <td><%= user.username %></td>
        <td><%= ticket.created_at.strftime("%H:%M, %B %d, %Y") %></td>
        <% if ticket.ticketmessages.last && ticket.ticketmessages.last.user_id %>
        <td>(user waiting for reply...)</td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like "just plain Ruby". Is this [tag:ruby-on-rails]?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that this is in fact a [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) project - not just plain Ruby.

In that case, long story short: Stop doing everything in the view. Use Rails and its conventions.

In your model, add a proper relationship to the user, and a couple of scopes

```
belongs_to :user

scope :open, where(status: :open)
scope :closed, where(status: :closed)
```

Also add a method

```
def waiting_for_reply?
  # I don't quite understand your logic (or your naming) here,
  # so I'll just shorten it, but otherwise leave it
  ticketmessages.last.try(:user_id).present?
end
```

I say I don't understand your logic, because something called `ticketmessages` implies there's a class called `Ticketmessage` - when it should be called `TicketMessage` as it's two words (or simply `Message`). And in that case, the relation should be `ticket_messages` with an underscore (or, again, simply `messages`).
Secondly, you check whether there is a (last) ticket, and whether its `user_id` is non-nil/non-false. But what does that prove? If there's any system to how it's set up, a message will *always* have a `user_id` because every message was written by a user. The real question (I assume) is whether that `user_id` is equal to *the ticket's `user_id`* - otherwise someone else wrote it. But that's not what you're checking, so I'm confused.

Anyway, in your controller, load two collections (and eagerly load the associated users):

```
@open_tickets = Ticket.open.includes(:user)
@closed_tickets = Ticket.closed.includes(:user)
```

In your view, extract the table itself into a partial, and only include HTML for the parts that actually differ. Note the call to `render` where we point it to the partial template it should use, and the local variables that should be made available to that template.

```
<h3>Open Tickets</h3>
<% if @open_tickets.any? %>
  <%= render partial: "tickets", locals: { tickets: @open_tickets } %>
<% else %>
  <h4>No open tickets</h4> <!-- this should just be a P element by the way -->
<% end %>

<h3>Closed Tickets</h3>
<% if @closed_tickets.any? %>
  <%= render partial: "tickets", locals: { tickets: @closed_tickets } %>
<% else %>
  <h4>No closed tickets</h4> <!-- see above -->
<% end %>
```

And here's the partial

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket Number</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Submitted by</th>
      <th>Created at</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% tickets.each do |ticket| %> <!-- here we use the local "tickets" -->
    <tr>
      <td><%= ticket.id %></td>
      <td><%= link_to ticket.title, ticket_path(ticket.url_token) %></td>
      <td><%= ticket.user.username %></td>
      <td><%= ticket.created_at.strftime("%H:%M, %B %d, %Y") %></td> <!-- this formatting stuff should be a helper method -->
      <td>
      <% if ticket.waiting_for_reply? %>
        (user waiting for reply...)
      <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```